# Why does runat="server" cause failure?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I use

```
<input type="date" id="DateRangeStart"/>
```

Code compiles and I get a (slightly weird) date selection input control

But I can't then identify it using `Forms.Request["DateRangeStart"]` in the code-behind
So I add `runat="server"`

```
<input runat="server" type="date" id="DateRangeStart"/>
```

But now code doesn't compile and it doesn't recognise my input type `date` ??

Comment: What compilation error are you getting? Can you post your code, reduced down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'm getting `Build (web): 'date' is not a valid type for an input tag.` - I'll try to recreate this to a solo solution

Comment: Change input to `Textbox` type. So `<asp:TextBox ID="DateRangeStart" runat="server" placeholder="Select Date" type="date"></asp:TextBox>` Also what browser are you using to render this?

Comment: Did you mean `Request.Form["DateRangeStart"]`? Note the order of the words and the square brackets

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ That did it, I needed it in an `asp:TextBox` type to get it to work

Comment: @jamheadart good, glad you can move forward now :)

Comment: @jamheadart try giving name tag same as id:- <input runat="server" type="date" name ="DateRangeStart" id="DateRangeStart"/>